# how to sum a field from 3 tables and display the results together

Tags: sql-server, select, sum

im using sql server and I have 3 tables called accnt, acc1152, and acc1167. each of these tables has an amnt field and a accno field with a few thousand records in it. i need to sum the entire amnt column for acc1152 and acc1167, then sum the amnt column in accnt for every record with the accno = '1152' then sum then sum the amnt column in accnt for every record with the accno = '1167'. then display the 4 sums together.

so the final result should like this

```
    totals
  SUMacc1152
  SUMacc1167
  SUMaccnt A
  SUMaccnt B
```

Ive tried these with no success:

```
SELECT SUM(amnt) FROM acc1167,
SUM(amnt) FROM acc1152,
SUM(amnt) FROM accnt WHERE ACCNO = '1167',
SUM(amnt) FROM accnt WHERE ACCNO = '1152'
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(amnt) FROM acc1167
SELECT SUM(amnt) FROM acc1152
SELECT SUM(amnt) FROM accnt WHERE ACCNO = '1167'
SELECT SUM(amnt) FROM accnt WHERE ACCNO = '1152'
```

Comment: Well, out `union all` between `select`s in the second query.

Comment: thank you, that is what was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'acc1167' as tbl_name,SUM(amnt) FROM acc1167
union
SELECT 'acc1152' as tbl_name,SUM(amnt) FROM acc1152
union
SELECT '1167' as tbl_name,SUM(amnt) FROM accnt WHERE ACCNO = '1167'
union
SELECT '1152' as tbl_name,SUM(amnt) FROM accnt WHERE ACCNO = '1152'
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
SELECT SUM(amnt) FROM acc1167
union all
select SUM(amnt) FROM acc1152
union all
select SUM(amnt) FROM accnt WHERE ACCNO = '1167'
union all
SELECT SUM(amnt) FROM accnt WHERE ACCNO = '1152'
```